# JSP page don't recognize tags

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Can anybody help me to understand, what is wrong with my jsp-page. The 'foreach' loop is working, but the item's members don't display (simple text occurs on their place)

```
    <c:forEach items="${model}" var="item">

      <tr>
        <td height="10"><hr width="100%" size="2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        ...
        <td width = 10%>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="20"><p>Author: $(item.author)</p>
                        <p>Last updated: $(item.timeLastUpdated)</p>
                        <p># comments: $(item.commentsCount)</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="45"><p>$(item.text)</p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="45"><p><%=item.text%></p></td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

The page's controller is the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(Locale locale, Model model) 
{
    logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());
    logger.info("Running SIMPLE_BLOG");

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);       
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);     
    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    Iterable<Topic> listTopic = service.findAllTopics();

    return new ModelAndView("home", "model", listTopic);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
${item.author}
```

not

```
$(item.author)
```

The syntax for [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) is `${ }` not $( )

Comment: You need to do this for all your expressions in parentheses e.g.  $(item.timeLastUpdated) should be ${item.timeLastUpdated}